# SQL Error subquery must return only one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, psql

I wish to do when the condition of if is met, the values ​​of the two columns can be changed. I am new to SQL can you plsese help me?  My code:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
IF (select * from V1 where starting-lag >= 7)
THEN
   INSERT INTO newstart VALUES (starting - 7);
   INSERT INTO newend VALUES (starting - 8);
ELSE
   INSERT INTO newstart VALUES (lag +1);
   INSERT INTO newend VALUES (lag);

END IF;
END
$do$
;
```

```
V1(id, starting, ending, lag, lead,newstart,newend)
```

It returns:

```
ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
LINE 1: SELECT (select * from V1 where (starting-lag) >= 7)
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT (select * from V1 where (starting-lag) >= 7)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at IF
```

I tried to use update but it returns `DETAIL:  Views that return window functions are not automatically updatable. HINT:  To enable updating the view, provide an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger or an unconditional ON UPDATE DO INSTEAD rule.`

Comment: `IF (select * from V1 where starting-lag >= 7)` makes no sense. You compare a scalar (`7`) to a set of tuples. Maybe you you want to check if any row meeting the condition exists? It's also unclear what value you reference by `starting` and `lag` in the `VALUES` clauses. [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables, `INSERT` statements for sample data for them and the desired result with that sample data in tabular form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *suspect* that you want an `update` statement rather than `insert`, because you are mentionning that youw ant the values to be *changed*. That's what an `update` does, while an `insert` creates new rows.

The logic you are looking for could be:

```
update v1
set 
    newstart = case 
        when starting - lag >= 7 then starting - 7
        else lag + 1
    end,
    newend = case 
        when starting - lag >= 7 then starting - 8
        else lag
    end
```

There is no need for a `do` block to implement this logic, a straight query is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help but why it returns  error ```DETAIL:  Views that return window functions are not automatically updatable. HINT:  To enable updating the view, provide an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger or an unconditional ON UPDATE DO INSTEAD rule.```